# SQL Server: Can a query return results to multi-part searches in one step?

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

Say we have a car dealership website that allows searching for make, model, type and year. The full search term would be **Toyota Corolla Sedan 2006**. "Toyota" is represented by a simple numeric ID key in the main *Cars* table, as are "Corolla" and "Sedan". The keys for Make, Model and Sedan reference the *Makes*, *Models* and *Car_Types* tables.

The query should return exact matches first, ie. all cars that are Toyota Corollas from 2006. Then the same query should return Corollas from years other than 2006, in decreasing order of relevance, so years closer to 2006 would be first, followed by years further away, and then it would return other Toyotas that weren't Corollas but still sedans, and finally other Toyotas that were neither Corollas nor sedans.

It would be tolerable (if cumbersome) to write a multi-stage dynamic SQL query with UNIONs based on the search parameters, but I can't help but feel there's an elegant, one-step way to do this. Of course, if there isn't a better, more sensible approach then I'll probably end up going with the UNION approach:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT Car_ID, 1 as ResultOrder FROM Cars 
    WHERE Make_ID = 1 AND Model_ID = 5 AND Car_Type_ID = 7 AND Year = 2006
  UNION
  SELECT Car_ID, 2 as ResultOrder FROM Cars 
      WHERE Make_ID = 1 AND Model_ID = 5 AND Car_Type_ID = 7    
  UNION
  SELECT Car_ID, 3 as ResultOrder FROM Cars 
      WHERE Make_ID = 1 AND Car_Type_ID = 7
  UNION
  SELECT Car_ID, 4 as ResultOrder FROM Cars 
      WHERE Make_ID = 1
  ) AS Results
ORDER BY ResultOrder
```

It feels clunky. It's inelegant. If you can suggest a more sound, more performant approach I'm all ears. Thanks for your time!

Comment: What if you used a case statement with all of your logic in the where clauses and check for is not null for each of the fields.  If they're all not null then ResultOrder = 1, if three of the four are not null then 2, etc...I'm suggesting something similar to sgeddes but instead of checking for the values below just check to see if they're not null.  If all of them are not null it found an exact match, etc..

Comment: You need at least couple of fixed/non-optional filtering conditions to make it performing well if you want to run it with a single select. Because all other conditions will be optional - too many `OR`s mean nothing but `scan`.

Comment: Thankfully we're dealing with hundreds of records rather than thousands or millions so the performance has a natural limit. If the dealership were to grow suddenly they'd have enough money to throw hardware at the problem ;) But I certainly take your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another option using a `case` statement:

```
SELECT Car_ID, 
    CASE WHEN Model_Id = 5 AND Car_Type_Id = 7 AND Year = 2006 THEN 1 
         WHEN Model_Id = 5 AND Car_Type_Id = 7 THEN 2 
         WHEN Model_Id = 5 THEN 3 
         ELSE 4 
    END as ResultOrder
FROM Cars 
WHERE Make_ID = 1 
ORDER BY ResultOrder
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use expressions in the order by.

```
SELECT car_id
FROM cars
WHERE Make_ID = 1
ORDER BY Year = 2006, Car_Type_ID = 7, Model_ID = 5
```

Comment: This will error in SQL Server, but you can fix it with a `CASE` expression this would work in MySQL.

Comment: This is very interesting. I'll be reading up more on this approach for sure. Thanks for a solution that is certainly much more elegant! My platform is SQL Server but the logic will stand me in good stead on future MySQL projects.